# Call to undefined function paginate()

Tags: php, laravel

```
 return $data = DB::select("SELECT orders.*,SUM(products.`product_price`*order_product.`qty`) AS 'total' ,users.`name`,orders.created_at as 'date'
                    FROM orders INNER JOIN order_product ON
                    orders.`id` = order_product.`order_id` 
                    INNER JOIN products ON
                    products.`id` = order_product.`product_id` 
                    INNER JOIN users ON 
                    users.`id` = orders.`user_id`
                    GROUP BY orders.`id`
                    ")-paginate(10);
```

Comment: Please elaborate and format your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the future, please actually *ask a question* instead of just dumping your code and an error message.

Comment: Actually I prefer going straight to the (obvious) error message than "Hello sir, good morning, my name is J. Ahmed, PHP developer, and I'm developing an online tool of cow management, and in the middle of my work session I got the following error message appearing in my 17"monitor screen:*** Can you find out why did I get such an error, and helping me fixing it?" "

Comment: @Amarnasan I think you are missing rickdenhaan's point.  We don't want the fluff, but we do want to see an intelligent question asked.  This not only benefits volunteers who want to post a solution, but also future researchers who would benefit from the clarification.

Comment: @Amarnasan Just a simple "Why is my code causing this error?" will do. Don't just dump code in the question with an error message in the title and *assume* someone will spend time and effort looking at the code to see what's wrong. That's just rude. We're here to help when asked, but at least have the decency to actually ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in your code, it's missing `>`, it should read

```
->paginate(10);
```

and not

```
-paginate(10);
```

Comment: Stackoverflow, debugging your code since 2008.

Comment: It's like /r/PHPhelp :-D

Comment: I'll do that next time.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but it's not technically a syntax error. Without the `>` PHP actually thinks you're trying to subtract the result of the undefined paginate function, but it's syntactically correct.